# Passing the data-id from anchor tag to html.beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have table and `<tbody>` of this table is getting filled from the list in the model.

The list has id for each item which is getting assigned to data-id in anchor tag

```
<tbody>                       

    @foreach (var item in Model.eList.ToList())
    {                               
        <tr>
            <td><a href="@Url">@item.FullName</a></td>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td><a data-id="@item.Id" data-open="Event">Event</a></td>
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

I have div with Id Event like this

```
<div id="Event" class="reveal" data-reveal>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "Profile", new { id = data-id}, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <label>confirm</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" id="Edits" />          
    }
</div>
```

When user clicks on anchor tag it will open the div with `id="Event"`. But how do I pass data-id for that particular record to div with `id="Event"`, from there it will be posted to controller with action cancel.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a hidden input element inside that form.

```
<div id="Event" class="reveal" data-reveal>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "Profile"))
    {
        <input id="dataId" name="id" value="" type="hidden" />
        <label>confirm</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" id="Edits" />          
    }
</div>
```

and when user clicks the anchor tag, read the value from the data-id attribute of the clicked element and set it as the value of the hidden element.

```
$(function(){
   $("[data-id]").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var id=$(this).data("id");
      $("#dataId").val(id);

      // your existing code to open the div with form
      / /$("#Event").show();
  });

});
```

When the user submits the form, the id value we set to the hidden input will also be submitted.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/yeluhekuqa/edit?html,js,output) is a js bin sample.

Comment: I tried to view the div with id="Event". that doesn't show the div.

Comment: Sorry ! I am not following what you are saying. Are you saying you are not able to show the div with id event ? As per your question, that part was working fine.(**When user clicks on anchor tag it will open the div with id="Event"**)

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear. JsBin which you have provided clicking on Event in the list should open a modal window, which should have textbox and save button with id

Comment: how are you currently opening the modal dialog ? Can you include that in the question

Comment: So, In my foreach loop the anchor tag has data-open html attribute with "event" name, and I have a div with the "event"- id when user clicks on anchor tag the div with "event" has data-reveal attribute which will open up the modal window

Comment: **which will open up the modal window**. Without know how you implemented this part, it is hard to say. For example: If you are making an ajax call and load the modal content, you will pass the clicked items id attribute value in the ajax request and use that to set the value of hidden input. You need to share the relevant parts of code which implement "opens the modal" part

Comment: I have added $('#Event').modal('show') instead of $(''#'Event').show(). This worked like charm. Thank you for putting up a JSBin.

Answer (score 1):

You can post Id in either -

1. Query String as `new {id = item }`, or
2. Hidden Field as `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item">`

*For example,*

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.eList.ToList())
    {
        <tr>
            <td><a href="@Url">@item.FullName</a></td>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "Profile", new {id = item }, 
                   FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <a data-id="@item.Id" data-open="Event">Event</a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item">
                    <div id="Event" class="reveal" data-reveal>
                        <label>confirm</label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" id="Edits" />
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: I tried it, but clicking on submit button in modal pop window doesn't trigger controller action.

Comment: If you use the first approach, you will need to add ***id*** parameter to ***Cancel*** action method *in addition to the view model if you have one*. For example, `Cancel(ViewModel model, string id) { }`

Comment: I have been using the example which you have provided- which is using hidden varaible

Comment: `public ActionResult Cancel(int id)
        {
            //Some code
            return RedirectToAction("Profile");
        }`

Comment: Do you have [HttpPost] attribute on the top of Cancel action method?

Comment: No.. I have other forms where submit button directly triggers controller action

Comment: You are performing HttpPost, so Cancel action method need [HttpPost]  attribute.